# Add role to user who reacts to bot message problem

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have a command and the bot responds with a message and adds a reaction to it, if the person who types the command reacts to it they get the role, but I want anyone to be able to react to it as I only want to type it once. it works but only for the person typing the command.

I've tried using other solutions but none other seem to work.

```
client.on("message", (message) => {

    client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
        if(reaction.emoji.name === "") {
            const guild = client.guilds.get('563851342532313088')
            const member = message.member;
            console.log(user.id);
            const role = guild.roles.find(role => role.name === 'Todosquad');
            member.addRole(role)
        }
    });
```

Console.log(user.id); prints everyone who reacted but it still won't give them the role.

Comment: You shouldn't do this. Look up reaction collector. That will do exactly what you want, without having to add many events

Answer (score 1):

The `messageReactionAdd` event has two parameters - `MessageReaction` and `User`.
In your example, those would be `reaction` and `user`. You are utilizing the `reaction` parameter to ensure that the reaction added in in fact the one you want. However, when it comes to adding the role to the person that added the reaction, you are referencing `member` which is actually the person that sent the message (`message.member`), not the person that added the reaction to the message.

To add the role to anyone that reacts, you'd need to
Change:

`member.addRole(role)`

To either an async event with: ( `client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) =>` )

```
const guildmember = await guild.fetchMember(user);
guildmember.addRole(role);
```

Or do:

```
guild.fetchMember(user).then(guildmember => guildmember.addRole(role));
```

*Edit: the `addRole` function only exists on the `guildMember` object since you can only add a role to someone in a guild.*

Comment: this gives me "user.addRole is not a function"

Comment: Ah, your User needs to be a GuildMember try doing `var guildmember = guild.fetchMember(user);`

Comment: ```client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
  if(reaction.emoji.name === "") {
   const guild = client.guilds.get('563851342532313088');
   console.log(user.id);
   const role = guild.roles.find(role => role.name === 'Todosquad');
   const guildmember = guild.fetchMember(user);
   guildmember.addRole(role);
  }
 });
```
also gives me "guildmember.addrole is not a function"

Comment: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=addRole
it definitely is though

Comment: I made an edit to the Post, you are missing the fact that `fetchMember` is `async` and needs a `.then` or `await`